# How to pause downloading in Node.js by request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, electron

How can I pause while downloading a file and start again?

Now I'm making download and show progress function with Node.js, javascript, html and electron. I thought it would be better if I can add pause function too.

I searched the request module, but I couldn't find event about pausing download. this is my first time using node modules.

Is there any event that I can add on my code? thanks!

referred by [this post](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/228/how-to-download-a-webfile-with-electron-save-it-and-show-download-progress).

```
//download.js

var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

function downloadFile() {
    var a = event.currentTarget;
    var td = a.parentElement;
    var tr = td.parentElement;

    var id = '';
    var fileSize='';
    fileSize = '' + tr.querySelector('td').getAttribute('id');
    console.log(fileSize);
      var progressBar;
      var display;
    progressBar= tr.querySelector('progress');
    display= tr.querySelector('span');
    progressBar.value = 0;
    display.innerText = '0%';
  // Save variable to know progress
  var received_bytes = 0;
  var total_bytes = 0;

    var fileURL = "http://speedtest-ny.turnkeyinternet.net/"+fileSize;
  var finalPath = "./resources/"+fileSize;
  var req = request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: fileURL
  });

  var out = fs.createWriteStream(finalPath);
  req.pipe(out);

  req.on('response', function(data) {
    // Change the total bytes value to get progress later.
    total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
    progressBar.max = total_bytes;
  });

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // Update the received bytes
    progressBar.max = total_bytes;
    received_bytes += chunk.length;
    progressBar.value = received_bytes;
    display.innerText = Math.floor((progressBar.value / progressBar.max) * 100) + '%'
  //  showProgress(received_bytes, total_bytes);
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    //alert("File succesfully downloaded");
  });
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<!-- download.html -->

<table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="blueone">

      <tr><th>파일명</th><th >진행상황</th><th><a onclick="downloadClick()">다운로드</a></th></tr>
      <tr><td id="100Mb.dat" >File10MB</td><td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile2(event)">다운로드</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td id="100mb.bin">File100MB</td><td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile(event)">다운로드</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td id="500mb.bin">File500MB</td><td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile4(event)">다운로드</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td id="1000mb.bin">File1GB</td><td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile(event)">다운로드</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td id="10Gb.dat">File10GB</td><td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile3(event)">다운로드</a></td></tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: You cannot pause a download. You can abort a download, and if the server supports it, you can resume it later by requesting a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

Comment: You can [pause read stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause)

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr pause is work! can you look up my another question? pause() works ok but it's complicate when I call it out side of function.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455332/how-to-call-a-inside-function-out-side-of-javascript

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Do you know why "pause()" isn't completely stop the downloading? when I execute resume() after pause(), it didn't start where it stopped, Is this still downloading under the background?

Comment: To stop you need to use [destory](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_destroy_error)