# how to call function inside of the function in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

How can I call "stop()" at HTML?

It's inside of downloadFile2().

**js example**

```
  function download() {
      var req = request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url
      });
      var out = fs.createWriteStream(path);
      req.pipe(out);

      function stop(){
       req.pause();
      }

      req.on('response', function(data) {
      });
      req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        stop();//I want to execute this method at html .
      });
    }
```

**html**

```
  <tr><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile2(event)">download</a></td><td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="downloadFile2.innerfunc();" value="ACTION">stop~!!!</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Be specific to your problem, Don't post all code, Just post logic.

Comment: @MehulPrajapatiI changed the whole question!

Comment: If you can modify the script, you can define `req` as a global variable ( `var req;` outside of fucntion) and also put the **stop** function, out of the **download** function so you can call it directly.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I tried both. doesn't work. when i define [req] as a global variable it doesn't work, and stop() also have error of  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `events`, Call `stop` function from `HTML`.

```
const events = require('events');
var EventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function download() {
    var req = request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url
    });
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    req.pipe(out);

    EventEmitter.on("stop",function(){
        req.pause();
    })

    req.on('response', function (data) {
    });
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        stop();//I want to execute this method at html .
    });
}
function stop() {
    EventEmitter.emit("stop");
}
```

But make sure `download` function gets called before `stop` function.

Comment: wow! that works amazingly well. EventEmitter keep goes well with request object!

Answer (score 0):

you can call function inside of another by this

```
 function download() {
  var req = request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: url
  });
  var out = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  req.pipe(out);

  this.stop = function stop(){
   req.pause();
  }

  req.on('response', function(data) {
  });
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    stop();//I want to execute this method at html .
  });
}
```

Then call the child function by this

```
<td><a class="checkBtn" onclick="(new download()).stop();" value="ACTION">stop~!!!</a></td>
```

Comment: when I follow your suggestion with added console log, it calls stop function but didn't pause downloading, pause() didn't work, just show log.

Comment: Check that you have correctly send the headers and also check that you are pausing the download correctly what i can suggest

Comment: Or you can create an other question for this query